# How to get the value from parent class in child class in python

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance

I want to access the value of val in child class

```
class a(object):
    val=[]
    def func1():
        val=['cat','dog']
        print(val)

class b(a):
    #how to get the value of variable val
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Getting baseclass values from derived class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935587/python-getting-baseclass-values-from-derived-class)

Comment: Thank you jay shankar gupta

Comment: welcome Sharan Kumar L U you can make that comment useful by clicking on up arrow